# How to create reusable code in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I've been working on a mobile app for a couple of months. Now I want to develop other apps but reusing the code I've written. I'd like to have reusable code (ViewControllers) in order to be used in many projects. In this way, if there is some bug in one of these, I'd fix the bug and then apply the changes to all the projects that use my library. In short words, I'd like to know what is the best way to develop my own library for iOS with XCode. I've been developed for Android but I'm new in iOS development.

1. Is it possible to add my own library to CocoaPods?
2. Do you suggest any other alternative?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can create your *private, internal, pods* and make your applications depend on them. As an alternative you could use *git submodules* either.

But if you want you can even use both: having your `private pods`, which are also *git submodules* of your project, - they are usually called *Development Pods* - because you might want to fix a bug on your internal pod and push the fix immediately to the *bleeding edge* of your library as soon as you tested it on the application in which you spotted the bug in the first place.

A couple of interesting articles on this topic:

[Working with internal pods](http://albertodebortoli.github.io/blog/2014/03/11/cocoapods-working-with-internal-pods/)

[Development pods](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2014/07/development-pods/)

**On a totally side and obvious - I think - note**, you can do this manually as pointed out by user1118321.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a static library or a framework (shared library). From the "File" menu choose "New Project" and then click on "Framework&Library" under "iOS". Then choose "Cocoa Touch Static Library" or "Cocoa Touch Framework".

Comment: As of iOS8, it might be worthwhile to **not** start down the static library path and discover you want to share more than code.  With frameworks supported on iOS8+, starting down the framework path might be better, especially if there is an app extension in the future.

Comment: Ah, good point. I hadn't realized frameworks were finally supported. I'll update my answer.